# Deriving a formula with Resolution Calculus.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm trying to show with resolution calculus, that $G := \neg A \land B \land C$ is a logical consequence of the set $S = \{\neg A \lor \neg B,C \lor \neg D, B \lor \neg C, C \lor D\}$. I just can't for the life of me figure this out! I succeed getting $\{\neg A,C\}$ which is $\neg A \land C$ but I just can't figure out how to get $B$ in there and how to get rid of $\neg B$. As far as I understand they cancel each other out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you know $C$, then the only way to satisfy $B\lor \neg C$ is that $B$ is true too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbering the four given clauses:

$$\lnot A \lor \lnot B \tag 1$$
$$C \lor \lnot D \tag 2$$
$$B \lor \lnot C \tag 3$$
$$C \lor D \tag 4$$

Resolution of $(1)$ and $(3)$ removes $B$ and results in

$$\lnot A \lor \lnot C \tag 5$$

Resolution of $(2)$ and $(4)$ cancels $D$

$$C \tag 6$$

$(5)$ combined with $(6)$

$$\lnot A \tag 7$$

$(3)$ and $(6)$

$$B \tag 8$$

The three results $(6)$, $(7)$ and $(8)$ imply

$$\lnot A \land B \land C \tag 9$$

Comment: In short $$\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{\neg A\vee\neg B~,~}\dfrac{\dfrac{C\vee D~,~ C\vee\neg D}{C}\lower{1.5ex}{~,~ B\vee \neg C}}{B\wedge C}}{\neg A\wedge B\wedge C}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am very surprised that you were able to isolate $\neg A$ and $C$, and yet not get $B$ ... So surprised in fact, that I suspect that you really only got to $\neg A \lor C$ instead.  That is, I suspect you did something like the following:

1. $\neg A \lor \neg B$ Given
2. $C \lor \neg D$ Given
3. $B \lor \neg C$ Given
4. $C \lor D$ Given
5. $\neg A \lor \neg C$ Resolve 1 and 3
6. $\neg A \lor D$ Resolve 4 and 5
7. $\neg A \lor C$ Resolve 2 and 6

In fact, when you write individual clauses as sets of literals, you would get:

1. $\{ \neg A, \neg B \}$ Given
2. $\{ C, \neg D\}$ Given
3. $\{ B , \neg C\}$ Given
4. $\{ C , D \}$ Given
5. $\{ \neg A, \neg C \}$ Resolve 1,3
6. $\{ \neg A, D\}$ Resolve 4,5
7. $\{ \neg A, C \}$ Resolve 2,6

And now the resulting clause is $\{ \neg A , C \}$ ... which is what you say you got ... but note that as a clause, that is $\neg A \color{red}\lor C$, rather than $\neg A \land C$!  Is that what happened?

Again, i suspect so, because in order to get to $\neg A $ and $C$ by themselves, you basically have to get $B$:

1. $\neg A \lor \neg B$ Given
2. $C \lor \neg D$ Given
3. $B \lor \neg C$ Given
4. $C \lor D$ Given
5. $C$ Resolve 2,4
6. $B$ Resolve 3,5
7. $\neg A$ Resolve 1,6

Comment: I see now. Stupid mistake by me... thanks for clarifying

Comment: @DariusTheGreat You're welcome!  It's the mistakes from which you learn most! :)